# how to breaking balloon by clicking mouse?

Tags: opengl, glut

my display() function, I bring the value of the balloon position to pop()

```
void display()
{
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// update balloon position
p = 0;

for(w=0; w<100; w++)
{
    p = rand() % speedrange;

    balloon[w].pos.y = balloon[w].pos.y + speed[p];
}

for(balloonBurst=0; balloonBurst<100; balloonBurst++)
{
    drawCircleOutline(balloon[balloonBurst]);
    if(mouseleft){
    pop(balloon[balloonBurst].pos.x,balloon[balloonBurst].pos.y);
    }
}
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

this is my mouse function

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

if (button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
{
    mouseleft = (state == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON);
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
    /*tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
    "balloonBurst.png",
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT);*/
    }
}
```

this is my pop() function

```
void pop (float x, float y)
{
    if( x - 0.1f <= mouseX/800 <= x + 0.1f && y - 0.1f <= 1 - mouseY/800 <= y + 0.1f)
    {
        tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
        "balloonBurst.png",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT);
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to link it and compare the value of mouse position and balloon position.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `picking` in OpenGL. There are two Methods for this namely `Ray Picking` and opengl `Selection Mode`. See [here](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/), [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm), [here](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html),  and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=lighthouse3d%20picking&oq=lighthouse3d%20picking&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6093j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=opengl%20picking).

Answer (score 0):

Draw every balloon with a different color, then get the color of the pixel where the mouse is, this will give you the color of the balloon (if you are pointing at one). For that, take a look at `glReadPixels`. Use some sort of list to see which balloon corresponds to which color. If you dont want to show this colors, you can clear the screen and render with your desired colors, textures, shaders, whatever.